# Exporting jar with VM arguments

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jar, swt

I've written a Java application with Eclipse that uses SWT for the UI. (see [SWT Exception when running jar: Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273960/swt-exception-when-running-jar-exception-in-thread-main-org-eclipse-swt-swtex/22275111?noredirect=1#22275111) for detail).

I exported as JAR and was having trouble getting it to run from Finder as well as from Terminal.  I finally got it to run from Terminal with `java -XstartOnFirstThread -jar CommonDenom.jar`

I still, however, cannot get it to run when I export as a JAR from eclipse.  This is because it needs the argument `-XstartOnFirstThread` bundled with it when it exports.  Then I noticed that in `Properties >> Run/Debug Settings >> commonDenom >> Edit >> (x)= Arguments` there is a tick-box that says "Use the `-XstartOnFirstThread` argument when launching with SWT."  But it was already checked.  So I figured this option only applies when launching the code with Eclipse, and doesn't apply to the exported JAR.

So I added the argument manually to the `VM Arguments` box in the same tab.  When I went to export as a runnable JAR, I noticed a warning that reads "VM arguments will not be part of the runnable JAR.  Arguments can be passed on the command line when launching the JAR.

Ultimately, I need a way to get this to launch from finder (be it JAR or otherwise) without having to open Terminal and launch it manually.  Yes, I can write a Shell script to launch it, but I feel there must be a simpler way.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.  The easy way is to create a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -XstartOnFirstThread -jar CommonDenom.jar
```

The user runs the script, which sets the arguments and runs Java.

The other way is to create an [Application Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW13).  It include a properties file (Info.plist) where you can set these properties.  You can also use Oracle's [appbundler tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) to create an application bundle.

Comment: If I create a shell script, do I this in Automator?  Or di I just do it in text pad?

If I want to bundle it as an app, can I use Automator to create a new Application?  Is that the same? And if so, what files/folders and/or actions get included int he workflow?  I'm assuming the jar itself, the classes, the manifest, and swt.jar?  Then once I save it, how do I edit the plist file to specify what i wanted to do in my original post?