# How to prevent "No jhdf5 in java.library.path" error in runnable JAR

Tags: java, hdf5

I have a Java program that reads and processes HDF5 files. I got the below error when I ran it on Eclipse (windows OS), and had to add a run configuration VM argument (-Dncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.H5.hdf5lib=\jhdf5.dll) to add the library and run properly. Now I'm exporting a runnable Jar file I get the error again, likely because it doesn't inherit the VM argument.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jhdf5 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at ncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.H5.loadH5Lib(H5.java:347)
    at ncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.H5.<clinit>(H5.java:274)
    at ncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.HDF5Constants.<clinit>(HDF5Constants.java:28)
    at ncsa.hdf.object.h5.H5File.<init>(H5File.java:99)
    at ncsa.hdf.object.h5.H5File.<init>(H5File.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at ncsa.hdf.object.FileFormat.<clinit>(FileFormat.java:229)
    at hdf5Tool.HDF5Interface.readNodeStructureH5(HDF5Interface.java:73)
    at wizardPages.DREAMWizard$STORMData$1.run(DREAMWizard.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286974/exporting-jar-with-vm-arguments), I see that two possible options are to create a shell script or application bundle to incorporate the VM argument.

However, I'm curious is there is a more simple way to identify the library for the runnable JAR file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you have specific needs, but maybe check out [jhdf.io](http://jhdf.io) it's a pure Java HDF5 library so doesn't require native libraries to be loaded. It should be simple to add to a Maven or Gradle project with standard dependencies.

It's quite an early stage but should support reading data from most HDF5 file, if it doesn't work open an issue.

Disclaimer: I am the author of jhdf so might be biased.

Comment: This project looks great, thanks for working on it! I saw a note in the readme that it is currently targeting read-only compatibility. Any chance you have plans to add writing capabilities?

Comment: I would like to, but its a question of time to work on it. Its a spare time project so can't really put any time scale on it. It's currently not a high priority.