# Maven/Tycho SWTBot Eclipse RCP

Tags: maven, user-interface, eclipse-rcp, tycho, swtbot

I would like to run my UI Tests SWTBot with Maven/Tycho and Tycho can't get my .product.
This my log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2017-12-02 16:36:32.573
!MESSAGE Product tychodemo.bundle.product could not be found.
***WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-12-02 16:36:32.760
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
...
```

[image]

This is my pom.xml:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>tychodemo.swtbot.test</artifactId>
  <packaging>eclipse-test-plugin</packaging>
  <parent>
    <groupId>tychodemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tychodemo.parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../tychodemo.parent</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho-version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <useUIHarness>true</useUIHarness>
          <useUIThread>false</useUIThread>
          <!-- use our product and application to launch the tests -->
          <product>tychodemo.bundle.product</product>
          <application>org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application</application>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Is it the right place to put my .product?

Thank you,
Antoine

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace for the "Application error"?
Do the tests run from the IDE?

Comment: I have this problem in both cas (terminal and ide), this my entire [log](https://gist.github.com/aomnes/4d1caf8b14379a9e5ba5b4975394002f)

Comment: This is my [project](https://github.com/aomnes/maven_tycho)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to be indicative of an [issue on the MacOS platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273960/swt-exception-when-running-jar-exception-in-thread-main-org-eclipse-swt-swtex).

To launch the tests on a mac you need to specify the `-XstartOnFirstThread` command line option in a separate profile:

```
<profile>
  <id>macosx</id>
  <activation>
    <os>
      <name>macosx</name>
      <family>mac</family>
    </os>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <ui.test.vmargs>-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XstartOnFirstThread</ui.test.vmargs>
  </properties>
</profile>
```